# Magento multi store setup get only store view wise products

Tags: multistore, products

I am working on magento one website - multiple store admin panel. As seen in screen shot, i want when i choose tee store view of main website then product of only tee store view displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

there is no relation between product and store view in the sense that you expect. The product can be associated to one or more websites, not store views.
And you can filter the products belonging to a certain website from the grid, from the last column before `edit` called `Websites`.

The top selector you are referring to is there so you can see the name of the product for a specific store view.

Comment: But we can create 1 website having multiple stores and they works on different domains. Say shoes and t shirts are two stores, then in that case shoes products display on show store and same for t shirts. So in that case how can show in admin with differentiation.

Comment: Maybe you have a different visibility set for each store view for the same product